# Sequelize get pure array without objects

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Dears i have the below query from Sequelize

```
 models.ProviderZoneCity.findAll({

         attributes: ['zoneId'],                            
         raw : true
         ,
         where : {
          status : 1
          }
         })
```

the returned data shows as

```
"providerHasZones":[{"zoneId":1},{"zoneId":2},{"zoneId":3}]
```

what i need exactly is the following structure

```
"providerHasZones":[1,2,3]
```

So it will be an array of id not array of objects, i tried (raw : true) but nothing changed :(

any advice?

Comment: Could you not just `map` over the data? `providerHasZones.map(zone => zone.zoneId)`

Comment: thnx dear, but how can i use map if i have (then(funcation(data))) ? 

i tried ---
}).map(zone => zoneId).then(function (providerHasZones) {

but it shows syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the results, e.g.

```
models.ProviderZoneCity.findAll({
     attributes: ['zoneId'],                            
     raw: true,
     where: {
       status: 1
     }
}).then(function(data) {
    return data.map(zone => zone.zoneId);
});
```

Comment: thnx dear, how can i use the map cuz i have (then(function(data))) ??

Comment: i tried 

}).map(zone => zoneId).then(function (providerHasZones) {

but it shows syntax error

Comment: updated my answer to assume the first function returns a promise

Comment: still am getting an error from the editor !! (expression expected)

Comment: This answer should work fine. Can you provide a little more info about the error?